# No me deja convertir de int a int[ ]

Tags: java

Saludos, tenía que hacer un array de doble dimensión pero no me deja almacenar valores enteros en dicho array, sin embargo en una dimensión sí, porque pasa esto?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int primerDim, segDim;
    int cont = 0;

    System.out.println("Introduce la primera dimensión: ");
    primerDim = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduce la segunda dimensión: ");
    segDim = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();

    int[][] doble = new int[primerDim][segDim];

    for (int i = 0; i < doble.length; i++) 
    {
        cont++;
        doble[i] = cont;
        for (int j = 0; j < doble.length; j++) 
        {
            cont++;
            doble[j] = cont;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el *loop*, tienes que asignar usando las dos dimensiones.

Algo así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doble.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < doble[i].length; j++) 
    {
        cont++;
        doble[i][j] = cont;
    }
}
```